# Applying horizontal scrollbar to a wide image in email

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am currently generating image visualizations in my outbound e-mails. I adhere to the 550 - 600 pixel e-mail width standard that I read from [here](http://blog.edmdesigner.com/600-px-is-the-optimal-responsive-email-width-why/). I have some visualizations that are tables, and at certain times, they can have more than 10 columns, which if I want to show everything, it would need to extend beyond 600 pixels.

I want to respect the 600 pixel width, and I was wondering if it is possible to have, say, a 1200 pixel image, but it is contained in a 600 pixel width that has a horizontal scrollbar so the image respects the 600 width rule, but they can still scroll horizontally to show the entire width.

I don't really have too much code, but this is the inline style used within my e-mail that I hardcode the width with:

```
style="position: relative; height: 600px; width: 600px;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Support for the `overflow` CSS property [is not great in email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). If you have a lot of iOS, Apple Mail, and webmail folks on your lists, you may be able to get away with using the `overflow` property on a `<div>` that wraps the `<table>`.

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>
        <!-- Your data -->
    </table>
</div>
```

But this won't work for Outlook, Android, and others.

---

**Another option:** Are you able to show a scaled down image in the email that *links* to a full-res version in browser?

```
<a href="link-to-full-res.png">
    <img src="" width="600" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;">
</a>
```

The image might not be 100% legible in the email, but the layout won't break and the experience should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Add the overflow property

```
style="position: relative; height: 600px; width: 600px;overflow-x:scroll"
```

Set the `overflow-x` property to `auto` if horizontal scrollbar needs to appear only when the width of the image is larger than 600px.
Use `overflow` property if you need both horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

Comment: Can you set a property that it only kicks in if the image is a certain width, i.e. greater than 600 pixels?

Comment: try overflow-x:auto;

Comment: @theGreenCabbage If you wrap the image inside a div element and give that element a fixed width / height, all you have to do is set `overflow: auto;`